# Pass parameter in request while using spring vmc form

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc form to submit request. I have a hidden variable which i want to pass to the controller. The hidden variable path is using a property which present in the model attribute object. Now I want to pass this hidden variable to the controller. For this one approach is to have the this variable in the model which curremtly is present. But I dont want to put this hidden variable in the model vo object. I just want to pass this hidden field as a request parameter to the controller. Is there any way to do that? If I use html input field `type=hidden`, will work ?

Please let me know. Below is the code for this. The value of the hi9dden field i am setting from javascript and doing the form submit.

- JSP file

  `<form:form id="form" modelAttribute="customerRelationshipBean">
  <form:hidden path="customerSearchBean.action" />  </form>`
- JS file

`document.getElementById("customerSearchBean.action").value='addCustomer';
document.getElementById("form").action = '/gcldw-web/customerSearch' ;
document.getElementById("form").method='POST';
document.getElementById("form").submit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you use's spring tags hidden element with a `path` attribute you establish an associatation with a model bean, and the value ends up in the model

Instead, you can simply add a plain input hidden element, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" id="secretValue" name="secretValue" value="" />
```

place the value to that element (via your js code) and add a suitable `@RequestParam` argument to your handle method e.g.

```
public String processSubmit(@ModelAttribute("customerSearchBean") CustomerSearchBean customerSearchBean, BindingResult result, 
                                 @RequestParam String secretValue) {
```